# Vector of vectors to JTable

Tags: java, vector, jtable

I save some data in Vector of vectors

```
Vector<Vector<String>> dataList= 
new Vector<Vector<String>>();
```

And I need to show that data in JTable, but problem is that when I use Iterator:

```
Iterator it=dataList.iterator();
```

A dont have next() or hasNext() method.
I tried to cast Iterator but id doesn't help... 
I tried with 2 forech loops but I have problem again

```
 for(Vector<String> v : dataList) {
for(String s: v) {
tableMod.addRow(v.get(s));
} 
}
```

But again I have problem because method get() need int parameter... 
Please give mi some helpful solution
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
for(Vector<String> v : dataList) {
    tableMod.addRow(v);
}
```

Comment: That is not solution I need, only shows elements from first row (iner vector)

Comment: Then your `dataList` is not populated the way you have described. Show the code how you populate it.

Comment: @Override
         public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
    if(oEvent.getEventType()==SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE){
           try{
        String inputLine=input.readLine();
    String[] rows=inputLine.split(",");
    for(String row: rows){
     row=row.trim();
     lista.addAll(Arrays.asList(row.split("\n")));
     dataList.add(lista);
    }

Comment: Looks like inner vector represents a row. In that case `tableMod.addRow(v);` should still work. Unless you are not parsing the data properly. If you still want to resolve this issue update your answer with the code you put in comment and sample of your file that you are parsing.

Comment: You keep on adding to the same `lista` Vector in `serialEvent`. I think you need to create a new Vector inside `serialEvent` in `for(String row: rows){` block.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE!
I have to send results from Arduino do Java by serial port and show them in table. I posted there image of results I get in java program and codes in Arduino and Java

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnKvF.png)

My Arduino code:

```
 #define pinPWM 6
 #define analogPinIn A0 
 #define analogPinOut A1

const int r = 68;
const int R = 470;

int valAnalogPinIn; 
int valAnalogPinOut; 

int Udig[10]={120,135,150,165,180,195,210,225,240,255};
int voltageDigi,ii=0;
int noMeasuring=30;
float voltageIn;
float voltageOut;
float avrVoltageIn;
float avrVoltageOut;
float U;

void setup() {
 pinMode(pinPWM,OUTPUT);
 Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {

int br=0;
float Uin, Uout, Ia;

 while(ii<=10-1){
 analogWrite(pinPWM,Udig[ii]);
 Serial.print(Udig[ii]);  
 Uin=measurUin();
 Uout=measurUout();
 U=Uin-Uout;
 Ia=U/r;
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(Uin);
 Serial.print(",");
 Serial.print(Uout);
 Serial.println();


 ii=ii+1;
 delay(1);

  }    

}

float measurUin(){

 long sumVoltageIn=0;

 for(int i=1;i<=noMeasuring;i++){
valAnalogPinIn=analogRead(analogPinIn);
sumVoltageIn=sumVoltageIn+valAnalogPinIn; 
delay(1);

}
avrVoltageIn=sumVoltageIn/noMeasuring; 
avrVoltageIn=avrVoltageIn*(5.0/1024);

 return avrVoltageIn;
}
float measurUout(){

 long sumVoltageOut=0;

  for(int i=1;i<=noMeasuring;i++){
 valAnalogPinOut=analogRead(analogPinOut);
 sumVoltageOut=sumVoltageOut+valAnalogPinOut; 
  delay(1);

  }
  avrVoltageOut=sumVoltageOut/noMeasuring; 
  avrVoltageOut=avrVoltageOut*(5.0/1024);

  return avrVoltageOut; 
}
```

My Java code:

```
public class SerialTest extends JFrame implements SerialPortEventListener{


SerialPort serialPort;

  Vector<String> header;
 Vector<Vector<String>> dataList=new Vector<Vector<String>>();
 Vector<String> lista=new Vector<String>();

DefaultTableModel tableMod;

private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = { 
        "/dev/tty.usbserial-A9007UX1", // Mac OS X
                    "/dev/ttyACM0", // Raspberry Pi
        "/dev/ttyUSB0", // Linux
        "COM8", // Windows
};
private BufferedReader input;
private OutputStream output;
private static final int TIME_OUT=200;
private static final int DATA_RATE=9600;
JButton btn=new JButton("Insert");

SerialTest(){
    super("Serial Test");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    header=new Vector<String>();
    header.add("PWM");
    header.add("Uin");
    header.add("Uout"); 
    btn.setSize(70, 50);
    JPanel panelbtn=new JPanel();
    panelbtn.add(btn);
    tableMod=new DefaultTableModel();
  JTable table=new JTable(tableMod);
   tableMod.addColumn("PWM");
    tableMod.addColumn("Uin");
    tableMod.addColumn("Uout");
 btn.setVisible(true);
 btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
            for(Vector<String> v: dataList){
                    tableMod.addRow(v);
            }       
        }
     });
  JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.add(panelbtn);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500,70));
    JScrollPane scrollPane=new JScrollPane(table);
    getContentPane().add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    getContentPane().add(panelbtn, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void initialize(){
    //System.setProperty("gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts", "/dev/ttyACM0");

    CommPortIdentifier portId=null;
    Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

    while(portEnum.hasMoreElements()){
        CommPortIdentifier currPortId=(CommPortIdentifier)portEnum.nextElement();
        for(String portName : PORT_NAMES){
            if(currPortId.getName().equals(portName)){
                portId=currPortId;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(portId==null){
        System.out.println("Could non find COM port");
        return;
    }

    try {
        serialPort=(SerialPort)portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),TIME_OUT);
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
        input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
        output=serialPort.getOutputStream();
        serialPort.addEventListener(this);
        serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
        serialPort.disableReceiveTimeout();
        serialPort.enableReceiveThreshold(1);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }   
}

public synchronized void close(){
    if(serialPort != null){
        serialPort.removeEventListener();
        serialPort.close();
    }
}

@Override
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
    if(oEvent.getEventType()==SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE){
        try{
            String inputLine=input.readLine();
            String[] rows=inputLine.split(",");
            for(String row: rows){
                row=row.trim();
                lista.addAll(Arrays.asList(row.split("\n")));
                dataList.add(lista);
            }

            System.out.println(dataList);

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }return;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    SerialTest main=new SerialTest();
    main.initialize();
    main.setVisible(true);


    Thread t=new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{Thread.sleep(100000);}catch(InterruptedException ie){}

        }
    };
  t.start();
            }
        }
```